# Why commented codes of HTML not converting whlie jade conversion

Tags: html, css, templates, pug

I am trying to convert `HTML` code chunk to jade using some online tools but none seems to work for me, let me now what I am doing wrong here as I am new to jade so using these tools.

**HTML code** -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js sidebar-large"> <![endif]-->
```

**Returned jade code** -

```
doctype html
html.no-js.sidebar-large
  // <![endif]
```

I am converting this chunk by chunk as my html file is too big so exceeds the word/character limit while using.

Tools Used -

1. http://html2jade.vida.io/
2. http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

Comment: Not a Jade user but this seems to be what you’re after: https://gist.github.com/kmiyashiro/1140425

Comment: @polarblau Thx...it was due to the incomplete structure..I made the body/html closing tags available and the both tools worked correctly.

Comment: Great! Maybe you could post an answer with this information and accept  it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tools wont give you appropriate results until unless you provide them a clean markup with correct opening and ending tags.

In my above mentioned example it wont work as I have not included the `<html>` after `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

So correct code is  -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js sidebar-large lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js sidebar-large"> <![endif]-->
```

**JADE** result -

```
!!! 5
html
//if lt IE 7
  //if IE 7
  //if IE 8
  //if gt IE 8
```